# Designing a resonator circuit: drive level considerations?

Tags: oscillator

When you design an oscillator circuit for a Quartz crystal, you have to take the maximum drive level of the crystal into consideration and add a damping resistor to keep the actual drive level below that value.

For ceramic resonators I seem to be unable to find a conclusive answer if I have to do the same.

I found the [FAQ by Murata](https://www.murata.com/support/faqs/products/timingdevice/ceralock/char/cch0004) stating:

> Q: Is it necessary to consider drive level for CERALOCK®?
>
> A: Variations of drive level have small influence on CERALOCK®, so it is
>   not necessary to consider drive level for CERALOCK®.
>   [image: ESR and drive level in CERALOCK]

Which would indicate that it just doesn't care. I've also not found any mention of drive level in the datasheets of the resonators.

Still keeps me wondering how much drive level I should be aiming at, surely I can't just pour 1 W into the resonator and hope it'll work for 20 years.

So questions:

1. What is the maximum drive level for a ceramic resonator?
2. Is there a recommendation on the minimum drive level to provide a stable and resilient (against external disturbances) oscillation?

Comment: Do ceramic resonators have HIGH Q, where stored energy might cause unacceptably high mechanical stresses?

Comment: Have looked for this info too (not successfully). Perhaps an IIP3 measurement would indicate where losses become excessive. Or easier, a Q measurement done at various drive levels.